# Scraping names from multipages without clicking on the next button

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, selenium

I've written a script in python in association with selenium to harvest some coffee shop names from yellowpages. Although, the webpage is not javascript injected one, I used selenium for the purpose of experiment, specially how to handle multipage without clicking on the next button.

Upon execution I could notice that my script runs flawlessly and parses the names from that page. However, it does all this very slowly. Is there any way I can make it's performance faster than how it is now being limited within selenium?

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

for page_num in range(1,3): 
    driver.get('https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=pizza&geo_location_terms=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&page={0}'.format(page_num))    
    for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.info"))):
        try:
            name = item.find_element_by_css_selector('a.business-name span[itemprop=name]').text
        except:
            name = ''
        print(name)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is pretty much straightforward and understandable, but I would still work on the following stylistic and readability issues:

- *extract constants*. It might be a good idea to extract the URL template and maximum page number into separate constants, or as arguments of a function
- put your main execution logic into the [`if __name__ == '__main__'`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/771848) to avoid it being executed if the module is imported
- [*avoid using bare exception clauses*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14797375/771848). Be specific about the exceptions you are handling. In this case, `NoSuchElementException` is a good exception to handle if an item name is not found
- use `try/finally` to safely close the `driver` if it fails before quitting - this way you would eliminate a situation when you have opened "ghost" browser windows left from failed scraping tries

All things applied:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def scrape(url, max_page_number):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    try:
        for page_number in range(1, max_page_number + 1):
            driver.get(url.format(page_number))

            for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".info"))):
                try:
                    name = item.find_element_by_css_selector('a.business-name span[itemprop=name]').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    name = ''

                print(name)
    finally:
        driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url_template = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=pizza&geo_location_terms=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&page={0}'
    max_page_number = 2

    scrape(url_template, max_page_number)
```